# How to make marquee in android repeat just once

Tags: java, android, xml

I have tried marquee limit 1 but it does not work

```
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/marqueText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="26sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you are looking for the marquee animation. There is no XML attribute that you set for that purpose

[This](http://www.androidzeitgeist.com/2012/06/creating-marqueelayout-with-android.html) is a good link for the marquee animation in android. Hope it helps!

The XML attribute simply fades the textview if it goes out of your device screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `setSelected(true)` method of `TextView` in `onCreate()`

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.marqueText);
textView.setSelected(true);
```